# C++ switch not working with more than 2 cases

Tags: c++, input, switch-statement

I'm learning C++ so sorry for newbie question.
I'm doing exercises from S. Prata's Book. I'm currently on 6.4.
There is the code I've written:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void showmenu();
void request();
const int strsize = 20;
const int templeSize = 5;

struct temple {
    char name[strsize];
    char job[strsize];
    char psd[strsize];
    int preference;
};

int main(){
    temple members[templeSize] = {
        {"Alan", "spy", "Kret", 0},
        {"Bruce", "engi", "Mech", 2},
        {"Zac", "engi", "Robot", 0},
        {"Kevin", "teacher", "Kid", 1},
        {"Maverick", "spy", "Shadow", 2}
    };

    char choice;
    showmenu();
    request();
    cin >> choice;
    while (choice != 'q'){
        switch(choice){
            case 'a' : for(int i; i< templeSize; i++)
                           cout << members[i].name << endl;
                       break;
            case 'b' : for(int i; i< templeSize; i++)
                           cout << members[i].job << endl;
                       break;
            case 'c' : for(int i; i< templeSize; i++)
                           cout << members[i].psd << endl;
                       break;
            case 'd' : for(int i; i < templeSize;i++){
                           switch(members[i].preference){
                                case 0: cout << members[i].name; break;
                                case 1: cout << members[i].job; break;
                                case 2: cout << members[i].psd; break;
                            }
                        }

            default :   request();
        }

        showmenu();
        cin >> choice;
    }

    cout << "\nBye!\n";
    return 0;
}

void request(){
    cout << "Choose one option:\n";
}

void showmenu(){
    cout << "a. names          b. jobs\n"
            "c. psds    d. preferences\n"
            "q. Quit\n";
}
```

I have no ide what is wrong with that. Code is compiling (I'm using code::blocks), but only for cases 'a' and 'b'. When I input 'c' or 'd' it just showing menu again. Same if I choose a/b more than once.
I've found other solution via google, but I realy want to know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Your case for `'d'` is missing a `break` after the switch.

Comment: Here's [something to play with](http://ideone.com/q4j8H2)

Comment: If it is C++ use std::string in structs etc and definitely not fixed arrays - so I would distrust that code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`i` is not initialized in any of your case statement for loops

Comment: ... which means you have undefined behaviour, and anything can happen. Including some cases working, some cases not working.

Comment: +1 - Will still call `showmenu()` every time after going through the switch statement though - no matter the input.

Answer (score 5):

You are calling showmenu() outside of your switch statement.  So no matter what the input you will leave the switch and call the function.

```
switch(choice){
    ...
}
showmenu();
...
```